# Problemas con la integración de un acordeón en wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estoy integrando un HTML hecho en bootstrap en wordpress con custom field, y estoy teniendo problemas con un acordeón que cuando se despliega no me muestra el contenido completo.

Adjunto link del [html sin wordpress donde se ve el acordeón funcionando](http://qkstudiodemo.com/camconnection.com/requerimientos.html) 
y adjunto  [el que funciona mal integrado ya wordpress](http://qkstudiodemo.com/camconnection/web/requerimientos-del-sistema/)

También adjunto dicho script que use para el acordeón.

```js
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
 //Add Inactive Class To All Accordion Headers
 $('.accordion-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
 //Set The Accordion Content Width
 var contentwidth = $('.accordion-header').width();
 $('.accordion-content').css({'width' : contentwidth });
 //Open The First Accordion Section When Page Loads
 //$('.accordion-header').first().toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
 //$('.accordion-content').first().slideDown().toggleClass('open-content');
 // The Accordion Effect
 $('.accordion-header').click(function () {
  if($(this).is('.inactive-header')) {
   $('.active-header').toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header').next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
   $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
   $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
  }
  else {
   $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
   $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
  }
 });
 return false;
 });


 var clickElem = $('#accordion div h4');
 clickElem.on('click', function(){
  var $this = $(this),
   parentCheck = $this.parent('div');
  if( !parentCheck.hasClass('active')) {
   var accordItems = $('#accordion div');
   accordItems.removeClass('active');
   parentCheck.addClass('active');
  }
 });
```

```html
   <section class="container services bottomspace25">
    <div class="row">
     <div id="content">

      <div class="col-md-12 animated fadeInRight notransition">

       <img src="<?php the_field('imagen_de_logo'); ?>" class="img-resopnsive bottomspace10" style="width:250px;" />
                   <h2 class="smalltitle">
                    <span>
                    <?php the_field('titulo_de_requeriemiento'); ?>
                    </span>
                   </h2>

                   <?php if(have_rows('acordeon')):
                       while(have_rows('acordeon')): the_row();?>

        <div id="accordion-container">
         <h2 class="accordion-header"><?php the_sub_field('titulo_acordeon'); ?></h2>
         <div class="accordion-content">
          <?php the_sub_field('caracteristicas_del_producto'); ?>
         </div>
        </div>

                    <?php endwhile;
                   endif;?>


      </div><!--/ col 12-->
              </div> <!-- content -->  
    </div> 
   </section>
```

Comment: la div con id=content esta fijando el height de la misma a una valor absoluto, por eso no se te "extiende la pagina", alguna parte de tu codigo javascript lo debe estar haciendo, porque en el html que pegas no se ve que se fije ese numero.

Comment: Ahora que lo veo mejor, es seguro que eso te lo esta causando la libreria isotope, quitale el class="isotope" a la div con id=content,

Comment: Hola leonardo como estas? mmmm no sabes que no lo pude encontrar, encima estoy trabajando sobre un templeate que me pasaron.

Comment: El html que pegaste en la pregunta, estas seguro que es el mismo que el de la pagina que te esta fallando? porque aca no veo que esas div que te digo yo tenga la clase isotope, pero en el link de la web si inspecciono el html si lo tiene

Comment: Ah puede que me este heredando de otro lado entonces,es muy probable.

Comment: específicamente en el link este http://qkstudiodemo.com/camconnection/web/requerimientos-del-sistema/, si inspeccionas la pagina vas a encontrar que el slider esta dentro de esta div ´<div id="content" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 390px;" class="isotope">´ donde se nota que isotope esta fijandole el heigt a la div. deberia quedar solo asi <div id="content" >

Comment: Si ya esta ya lo pude solucionar, le cambie el nombre de ID, se ve que me estaba heredando de algun lado algo

Comment: Perfecto, saludos!

Comment: Gracias Leonardo!